# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Main in intelliJ and Maven build

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, program-entry-point

Here's my code which sets up the server using Jersey+ Grizzly combination from [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html). I haven't modified anything. also, all my files in the package com.example.

```
package com.example;
```

A rough skeleton of the Main.java which has the main(String[] args) is:

```
public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
              code;
       }   
}
```

Also, there are other .java classes which don;t have main method. The project is being built by Maven and I use IntelliJ. The two execution profiles I have are:

Working directory : Z:/IdeaProjects/com.example with command line arguements: 
clean test and exec:java

I understand that i need to run my Main but I don't know how to do it via Maven+IntelliJ. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I usually just right click on the main method and then click on the Run option. If you haven't downloaded all your dependencies, then go ahead and click on the Maven Projects tab, on the right side of the screen and run the compile stage to download all of your dependencies.

If you attached the error message you are getting that might help us narrow down the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You need a directory per package component. The path should be `com/example/Main`, not `com.example/Main`.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner , can you please tell me if I need to add after both commands?

Comment: You should be executing `mvn` from the root of your project. Your source code should be in `src/main/java/com/example/Main.java`. Maven will compile that into `target/classes/com/example/Main.class` and run it there.

Comment: Yes, I do have the directory as com/example/Main! still, i get the same error.